# background image sizes that wont generate OutOfMemoryError in BitmapFactory

Tags: android, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I have different landscape and portrait background images, and I followed the docs' recommendation of a ldpi:mdpi:hdpi:xhdpi ratio of 3:4:6:8, with my mdpi background image as 320x480, however, especially on rotations for xhdpi devices, I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` in in `android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset`... I'm guessing this is due to either my background images being too high of a resolution (I wouldnt think so since its just the size of the screen), or the fact that my images are png files that are 3-4 times larger than if i used high quality jpg files, I'm wondering if anyone knows for sure or has experience dealing with background images of the size i described without problems, because I'd rather just switch to jpg instead of having to lower the image resolution.

Comment: JPEG vs. PNG should not matter, as it is the decoded size that counts, not what the file size is. Use DDMS and MAT to determine exactly what bitmaps you have outstanding and what their in-heap sizes are.

Comment: Actually, switching to jpeg seems to have solved the problem for me, there are a couple other posts on SO where people seem to have had similar experiences too.

Answer (score 0):

Although switching to JPEG may have solved the issue for you, that doesn't mean it will work all of the time, especially if you have a large background image with the same name in different drawable-port and drawable-land folders.

Check out this link to find out how Google wants you to do this: [Displaying Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#read-bitmap)